# Understanding syntax in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have been coding in Angular for a little bit of time now and I have created Modules, Controller and Services so far but I recently just came across a piece of code which I am just not able to understand. It is someone else's code and I think author has tried to define a service but not like I have created. Normally when I create a service it looks like below:

```
app.factory('portabilityService', [
    '$resource', '$state', '$rootScope', function ($resource, $state, $rootScope) {
        return { //definition      };
    }
]);
```

- To me it is simple specify service name as the first argument inside Factory followed by all the dependencies and there you go.

Now, I came across some other code which looks like following:

```
(function () {
    /*
     * Manages which samples have been selected
     */


'use strict';

    angular.module('maintenance.portability.module')
        .factory('selectedSamplesSvc', service);

    service.$inject = [];

function service()
{
 //other function definitions
};

     })();
```

Now, this raises a lot of questions:

- First of all, is this really a service?
- If yes, what is service.$inject = []?
- Where should I add the dependencies?
- What is the purpose of the constructor service() here?
- Is it just a different way to create a service or there is a specific reason why we should define a service in this particular way?

Comment: you have a few too many question here.  It's not a bad thing to ask about the parts you are confused about, but the way you have presented the question, you'll likely get a lot of comments rather than answers, and the answers you do get may only cover *parts* of your concerns.  This might be something that using [chat] would be better for.

Comment: that being said, I'll still make an attempt at answering the question.

Comment: All your questions are answered here ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to address your questions in order:

First, yes, this is definitely a way to declare a service. It's not entirely far off from what you are normally used to using.

The normal syntax for declarations in angular is:

```
typeOfDeclaration('stringNameOfDeclaration', functionDeclaration);

function functionDeclaration(){..};
```

In JavaScript, a function is an object, so an *anonymous* function can be used in place of the `functionDeclaration`, for example:

```
typeOfDeclaration('stringNameOfDeclaration', function(){..});
```

This inline declaration is usually easier to write when you are only making a single declaration, and is the defacto standard for most tutorial examples.

**Note** that these rules apply to **all** angular components (`providers`, `filters`, `directives`, `controllers`, etc.)

By declaring the function as a separate object rather than inline, the declaration and the function are more easily managed.  You could, in theory, put the function itself into a different file (though this is not common).  Also, if you are declaring multiple functions, this syntax allows you to group the declarations together and the functions together, which is mostly a matter of preference and coding style.

The ***optional*** array of dependencies in your example are a way to manage Dependency Injection in cases where the code will be minified.  In this case, another alternate DI method is used, `service.$inject = [];`.  This array can be used instead of the inline array, i.e. `service.$inject = ['$resource', '$state', '$rootScope'];`  Again, this gives you a way to group your declarations in one place, your dependencies in another.

Answer (score 2):

All the answers boil down to this: *They're equivalent with equivalent definitions of the function passed to `.factory`*.

1. Yes, it's a service (based on the prior statement)
2. `$inject` is an alternative to your `[ names..., function(dependencies...) {...}]` syntax
3. The same way just now your function definition is separate.
4. It's the function you pass anonymously
5. It's preference for the most part but explicit `$inject` is beneficial for minimizing

For additional considerations on the matter (in part) and overall good reading give this [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) a look.